# (Verification) Prove $2^n \ge n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Tags: induction, solution-verification

$P(1)$: $2\ge 1$ (True)

Suppose $P(k)$ is true.

$P(k+1): 2^{k+1}\ge k+1$

We know that $2^k\ge k \implies 2*2^k\ge 2k$.

Thusly, it would suffice to show that $2k\ge k+1$ for $k\ge1$.

Suppose $2k<k+1$, then, $ k<1$ which contradicts the requirement of $k\ge1$.
Hence, $2k\ge k+1$, and by transitivity $2^{k+1}\ge k+1$.

Since $P(1)$ is true, by induction $P(n):n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is true.

**EDIT**: As mentioned in the comments, I fixed the first line (I had $2\ge 2).$

Comment: Your proof is fine !

Comment: Your proof seems fine!

Comment: The proof is good, but from the point of view of style, a proof by contradiction is not preferred when a direct proof is just as easy:
$$2k=k+k\ge k+1$$

Comment: @quasi Ah. True. I kinda have a habit of proving by contradiction but now I see that direct proof is possible

Comment: A minor remark. P(1) says $2\geq 1$ not $\geq2$.